# Array#split behaviour when accessing beyond the array boundry

Tags: ruby

An `irb` session is following:

```
>> ar = [:peanute, :butter, :and, :jelly]
=> [:peanute, :butter, :and, :jelly]
>> ar[0, 1]
=> [:peanute]
>> ar[4, 1]
=> []
>> ar[5, 1]
=> nil
```

Why ar[4, 1] does not return `nil` just like ar[5, 1]? Would someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Just so you know, it's peanut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002205) as a special case.

Comment: Special cases make programmers' lives miserable.

Comment: Mentioned but not justified. "Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range": in ar[4,1], this is so, yet it doesn't return nil, as it should. Very, very unusual for Ruby to suck in this manner. Maybe it's an "off-by-one" error ion the Ruby specs?

Comment: I totally agree that this a non consistent behaviour which is misleading as well...